# When is the product of a Schwartz function and a smooth function guaranteed to be a Schwartz function?

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

How can we classify functions $g \in C^\infty \left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ such that for all Schwartz functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $f g$ is again Schwartz?

I believe this question could be answered using a Paley-Wiener-like theorem for tempered distributions, but I am struggling to find something like that.

Comment: Sufficient: All partial derivatives of $g$ are polynomially bounded. I would guess that this is also necessary.

Comment: This is the characterizing property of the multiplier space $\mathscr{O}_{\rm M}$. This is treated in the book on distributions by Horváth.